# Библиотека PHP Word: как сделать так, чтобы скрипт не перезаписывал, а дополнял созданный docx?

Tags: php, классы, ms-word, docx, phpword

Написал парсер, хочу циклом записывать получаемые данные в .docx файл. Использую библиотеку PHP Word.

Обработка и загрузка данных производится не одним пуском программы. Скрипт отработал - пауза - запустили снова, еще некоторое кол-во информации обработал и тд (пришлось так сделать из-за лимитов по запросам). Так же порционно он должен записывать в docx. Вот код:

**Создаю экземпляр класса PHP Word:**

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setOutputEscapingEnabled(true);

$section = $phpWord->addSection(array('lineNumbering' => 'newPage'));

$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
```

**Дальше в цикле foreach() получаю xml и готовлю их к записи. Наконец, записываю:**

```
if($key === 0) {
            $section->addText('Отчет по публикациям информационного агентства');

        }

        $section->addText($res);

        $section->addText($lo);

        $section->addTextBreak();

        $objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');
```

Первый проход цикла успешно записывает информацию, но следующий, вместо того, чтобы записать ниже продолжение - удаляет старое и поверх записывает новое. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как записать новое ниже уже имеющейся в файле информации.

*На каждом проходе цикла в $res и $lo кладутся новые значения - url и заголовки..*

**Опробованные алгоритмы дозаписи, которые не сработали:**

```
 1)       if($key === 0) {
            $section->addText('Отчет по публикациям информационного агентства');

            $section->addText($res);

            $section->addText($lo);

            $section->addTextBreak();

            $objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');

        }

        $templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('helloWorld.docx');

        $templateProcessor->addText($res);

        $templateProcessor->addText($lo);

        $templateProcessor->saveAs('helloWorld.docx');
```

2. if($key === 0) {
   $section->addText('Отчет по публикациям информационного агентства');

   ```
        $section->addText($res);

        $section->addText($lo);

        $section->addTextBreak();

        $objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');

    }


    $fragment = $phpWord->addSection();

    $fragment->addText('ПРИВЕТ, ВСЕ РАБОТАЕТ НОРМАЛЬНО');

    $objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');

    sleep(30);
   ```

   }

**Полный код, как он есть**

```
$tmp = array_slice($matches[0], $_SESSION["time"], -1, true);

$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setOutputEscapingEnabled(true);

$section = $phpWord->addSection();

$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');

foreach ($tmp as $key => $value) {

    if (is_string($value)) {
        /*var_dump(substr($value, 21));*/
        $cut = $value;
        $output = 'https://yandex.ru/search/xml?user=&key=&query=' . urlencode($cut) . '&lr==ru&sortby=&filter=none&maxpassages=5&groupby=ocs-in-group%3D3';

        $result = file_get_contents($output);

        $al = simplexml_load_string($result);

        $clay = $al->{'response'}->results->grouping->group[0]->doc->title->hlword;
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($al);
        echo '<pre>';

        foreach ($clay as $sd) {
            $arr[] = '' . $sd . '';
        }
        $res = implode(" ", $arr);

        $arr = [];

        $lo = $al->{'response'}->results->grouping->group[0]->doc->url;

        if($key === 0) {
            $section->addText('Отчет по публикациям информационного агентства');
            
        }

        $section->addText($res);

        $section->addText($lo);

        $section->addTextBreak();

        $objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');

    if($key % 3 == 1) {
        $key = $key + 1;
        break;
    }

}

$_SESSION["time"] = $key;
```

Comment: docx - сложный формат, у которого строго детерминировано начало и конец, в отличии от txt, csv форматов, он не может быть записан методом "дописать в хвост". Для дозаписи - вам нужно его импортировать или открыть в либе которая понимает docx, дозаписать (внути структуры которая в памяти), а потом результат с новыми и старыми записями сохранить на диск.

Comment: Спасибо! Понимаю, что каким-то методом либы нужно воспользоваться, но перечитал раз 10 документацию.. не могу понять.. https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/  Думал, может, у кого сходная проблема была, и именно с этой библиотекой..

Comment: Проблема осталась? Или это просто так спасибо?

Comment: Где у вас открытие файла? Алгоритм "дозаписи": 1. Открыли файл А. 2. Дозаписали строки (допустим addText). .3. Сохранили в файл А. Пункт 1 - у вас не вижу.

Comment: @nick-n-a Добавил несколько своих попыток в нижней части вопроса..

Comment: За что "спасибо"? За то, что время уделили... Мне очень не удобно, что кого-то отвлекаю, просто свои идеи исчерпал уже (

Comment: Да, проблема осталась..

Comment: Как вариант, можно просто собрать все результаты работы скрипта за какое-то время в csv и потом оттуда за один раз записать в Word. Один раз скрипт записывает корректно..

Comment: Но хочется проще, чтобы сразу в Word писалось..